# Django default value in model based on data that hasn't been loaded yet

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

When creating migrations for Django I'm running into an instance where I need to set the default value for a custom user based on another table.

```
# models.py
def get_default_item():
    return Item.objects.filter(name='XXXX').first().id

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # ...
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=get_default_item)
    # ...
```

I'm running into two issues:

- I need to ensure that the table for Item is already created. I think I can do this using dependencies.
- I need to ensure that the Item "XXXX" is created before it is referenced. Unfortunately this can't happen until I migrate the data over because the Item IDs need to be consistent with the old system and (unfortunately) I can't use id 0 with a Django / MySQL combination because that has special meaning.

Is there a way to tell the migration "don't worry about this default for now, you'll get it later"?

Comment: It seems the answer in this particular case is "don't do that". I changed my user creation so it would pass this without requiring the model to have that as a default.

Still interested in how to do this though, as this seems like it should be workable.

Comment: Are you using Django's migrations to import the Item data, or are you doing that outside of Django?

Comment: They're outside of Django.